# WP Twenty Seventeen : Hiding the main menu and show the mobile menu always

Tags: css, wordpress

i would like to change the menu in twenty seventeen that the mobile Menu is always displayed.

This is what i have tried:

```css
.menu-main-container {
 display: none;
}

#top-menu {
 display: none;
}

.menu-toggle, .js .menu-toggle, .js .dropdown-toggle {
 display: block !important;
 z-index: 5;
}

.js .main-navigation.toggled-on > div > ul {
 display: block;
}
```

The problem is that the dropdown is hidden as well when i hide the main navigation.

Any ideas are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .js .menu-toggle, .js .dropdown-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}

.js .main-navigation > div > ul {
  display: none;
}
```